# how to slide right to left with use of jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i m trying to implement three  tag in div tag slide right to left and that time also two more  tag slide right to left so what can i do?
here is my php code,

```
 <body>
    <div id="collapsible_section">
        <ul id="collapsible_buttons">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="a">Button A </a>
                <div class="hidden_content1">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud </p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="aa">Button B</a>
                 <div class="hidden_content2">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation </p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="aaa">Button C</a>
                 <div class="hidden_content3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerc</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="custom.js"></script>
  </body>
```

here is css code,

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgb(255, 102, 102);
}

#collapsible_section {       
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 200px;
}

#collapsible_buttons {
    list-style: none;
}

#collapsible_buttons, #collapsible_buttons li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.a{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;  
    width: 70px; 
}
.aa{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 70px; 
}
.aaa{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 70px;
}
#collapsible_buttons li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hidden_content1 {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: none;
    width: 350px;

}
.hidden_content2 {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    width: 350px;
    display: none;
     width: 350px; 
}
.hidden_content3 {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 30px;
   display: none;
    width: 350px;  
}
```

here is my js code,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#collapsible_buttons .a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.hidden_content2').hide(2000);        
          $('.hidden_content3').hide(2000);

         $(".hidden_content1").toggle(2000);

    });

});
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#collapsible_buttons .aa').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();   

          $('.hidden_content1').hide(2000);

          $('.hidden_content3').hide(2000);

        $(".hidden_content2").toggle(1000);
    });

});


jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#collapsible_buttons .aaa').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();   

       $('.hidden_content2').hide(2000);

          $('.hidden_content1').hide(2000);

        $(".hidden_content3").toggle(2000);
    });

});
```

please tell me what can i do for only click  tag is slide left no another two  tag is slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkjdc92z/4/)

there were a few problems with your code

For best performance and concise code do NOT use multiple classes for
   same elements . such as `.a .aa .aaa` or
   `.hidden_content1,.hidden_content2` etc. Use a common class and then
   use different selectors to select the items that you want. Also you
   set same styles for example all `a`s but you write the styles 3
   times. That's not good practice. take a look at the changed HTML and
   CSS .

The above point is the same for the jQuery part. Do NOT write
 multiple click fuctions but instead write only one for all `a` and
 then select the `.hidden_content` using the [`next()` method](https://api.jquery.com/next/) .
 And so you will select only the adjacent content of the clicked `a`

> the .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following sibling

```js
$('#collapsible_buttons a').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var showMe = $(this).next(".hidden_content")
  $(showMe).toggle(1000).toggleClass("showMe")
    $(this).toggleClass("floatMe")
    $(this).parents("li").siblings("li").find(".hidden_content").hide().removeClass(".showMe")
  $(this).parents("li").siblings("li").find(".floatMe").removeClass()
  
    });
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgb(255, 102, 102);
}

#collapsible_section {       
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 200px;
}

#collapsible_buttons {
    list-style: none;
}

#collapsible_buttons, #collapsible_buttons li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;  
    min-width: 100px;

  float:right;
  clear:both;
  display:block;
 
}
a.floatMe {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

#collapsible_buttons li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hidden_content {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: none;
    width: 350px;
  float:left;
  clear:both;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collapsible_section">
        <ul id="collapsible_buttons">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Button A </a>
                <div class="hidden_content">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud </p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Button B</a>
                 <div class="hidden_content">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation </p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Button C</a>
                 <div class="hidden_content">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerc</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: not is this type ,when i m click on secound <a> tag that time toggle will be close.@Mihai T

Comment: ya thanks it will work . tkyou for good answer. bt when i click on secound <a> tag that time first <a> tag will br slide then after toggle is slide so what can i do for first toggle is slide?? @Mihai T

Comment: i don't understand . my code works like this : click on BUTTON A . content slides in . Click on BUTTON B , content from A hides, and content from B slides in . and so on . isn't that what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/nkjdc92z/4/

Comment: how can i do when i  click on button a that time also button width also incress is same as the hidden content??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nkjdc92z/5/ see here. add `width:100%` to `a.floatMe`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142683/discussion-between-kajal-jethva-and-mihai-t).